# Git Version controls tutorial for Xcode projects

Tags: ios, xcode, git

How to manage my Own project on server using Git version control.
Is there any tutorial for creating Server and adding project using Git commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't completely understand what you mean by creating server.

But if you mean creating a repository, then what you can do is go to one of the following websites and create a free account based on your need:

1. Github: https://github.com
2. Bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org

Now the above two have following features:

1. Github support unlimited free public respositories, and paid private repositories.
2. Bitbucket supports unlimited free private repositories.

You can start with creating a free account. Then go to your project repository root folder and execute the following commands in the same order:

for instance using bitbucket: -

git init

git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:username/abc.git

echo "Anil Gupta" >> contributors.txt

git add contributors.txt

git commit -m "Initial commit with contributors"

git push -u origin master

Thereon you can follow this tutorial:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/git/git_tutorial.pdf

Cheers!